# Javascript: assigning button id as a number inside of an innerhtml

Tags: javascript, button, for-loop, innerhtml

I have this problem, where I can't seem to put the number of the "xq" into being the id for the buttons while using innerHTML. 
Here's the code:

```
for (var xq = 0; xq < 3; xq++) {
    var pass = xq;
    tabletextvar = '<button id="buttontexto"; onclick="cancelObject(this.id);">Button</button>'
    document.getElementById("buttontexto").innerHTML = pass;
}

document.getElementById("tabletext").innerHTML = tabletextvar;
```

Button ID ends up being "buttontexto" when I really want it to be what innerHTML. It could be that you can't have another innerHTML inside an innerHTML.
Any tips or fixes would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think the problem is clear

Comment: do you want to have 3 buttons with ids `1,2 and 3` and text also the same

Comment: I think I can see what you're trying to do but id `buttontotext` doesn't really exists. tabletextvar isn't building the element/html. It will write it and for you to set the innerHTML for that elements you will need to write it to the page. I would recommend looking into creating dynamic elements for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have 3 buttons with id 1,2 and 3 then you need to append them, just using a variable inside the loop will override it and when the loop is over it will have the last value. You need to have a concatenated string.

```
var buttons = [];
for (var xq = 0; xq < 3; xq++) {
    buttons.push('<button id="',xq,'" onclick="cancelObject(this.id);">',xq,"</button>")
}

document.getElementById("tabletext").innerHTML = buttons.join('');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2q93z03/)

Comment: This is good, just what I need actually, but I really need to put the buttons creation inside tabletext otherwise the buttons aren't in the place I want them to be. Anyway to have this?

Comment: @Watulio the buttons are inside `tabletext` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2q93z03/2/

Comment: I didn't ask this right, sorry. I meant as in I already have things in tabletext.

Example:

 tabletextvar += "<td>";
                tabletextvar += valorParcial[xq];
                tabletextvar += "</td>";

This is something I have inside tabletextvar and I want every button to be aligned properly with each row

Comment: Screenshot of what I have right now

http://gyazo.com/57eb925506722646481e7b5e898a0bff

Is there a way to have the buttons there work just like the ones you did, but the only thing I'm missing is to have them inside of tabletext along with the rest of the table

Comment: @Watulio do you want to have 2 buttons in the same row?

Comment: @Watulio http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2q93z03/4/ - click on the button to check it

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a lot for helping me out here and putting up with my sort a enigmatic questions. I'm new to Javascript and stackoverflow!